# Set custom error levels in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, error-handling, e-notices

How can I set custom error levels with Zend Framework - say, I want to disable E_NOTICE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `Zend_Application` put the following line into your `application.ini`

```
phpsettings.error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

You can also use `error_reporting()` in your bootstrap like so:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

The error reporting levels a documented in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: It has to be phpSettings with capital S, otherwise it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

In application.ini, this works:

```
phpSettings.error_reporting = E_ALL^E_NOTICE
```

This won't work:

```
phpSettings.error_reporting = "E_ALL^E_NOTICE"
```

Answer (score 0):

ZF 1.11, application.ini.

This works:

```
phpSettings.error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE
```

This won't work:

```
phpSettings.error_reporting = E_ALL^E_NOTICE
phpSettings.error_reporting = "E_ALL^E_NOTICE"
```